# Flutter: How to use MaterialStateProperty to set ElevatedButton's minimumWidth?

Tags: flutter, widget, themes

I've been puzzling on this for a while.  I want 2 buttons with different text to be the same width.

I've achieved this by making ElevatedButton a child of SizedBox, but I'm concerned that the Button title text will be clipped if the users has the default font size set to large.

I can put a 'minimumSize' on the ElevatedButton's style attribute:

`style: ButtonStyle(minimumSize: ),`

But I don't have a clue how to set the minimumSize, it wants this:

> {MaterialStateProperty minimumSize}  Type:
> MaterialStateProperty   The minimum size of the button itself.
> The size of the rectangle the button lies within may be larger per
> tapTargetSize

I can't figure out how to set a MaterialStateProperty, Android Studio complains 'Abstract classes can't be instantiated.'  Help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This `MaterialStateProperty` is confusing when you want to use it for the first time. If you want to set `minimumSize` the same for all states possible in `MaterialState` (hovered, focused, pressed, ...) you can use this:

```
MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(width, height))
```

Or if you want to have different `minimumSize` for different states then this is the way to do it:

```
MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
  if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
    return Size(width, height);
  }
  return Size(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Cheers for your kindness Amir, that's exactly what I needed and that's a really complete answer, thanks so much. As an aside Putting a Button in a SizedBox with defined width will force the text within to wrap if it exceeds that width.  Setting "style: ButtonStyle(minimumSize:" however allows the button width to grow, but if the text still needs to wrap the minimum height doesn't respect the button's padding, it sizes itself to the font height, which makes it ugly in a different way to SizedBox. Nevertheless a superior solution in most cases I think.

Comment: You're welcome. As the property's name indicates it's defining button's minimum size and If you check the source code for `ButtonStyleButton` you can see that it's constraining the button using a `BoxConstraint` with the given minimum size. The exact size will be defined by your button's content and the constraint given by it's parent. @Sam